# Where can I get a SQL Query node source config for Rundeck

Tags: oracle, automation, rundeck

Rundeck 3.4.4 Community.

I have installed the Rundeck JDBC execution plugin (groovy-jsr223-2.4.21.jar, groovy-sql-2.4.21.jar & ojdbc8.jar in my /var/lib/rundeck/lib dir) and created a resource file that is abled to authenticate to my Oracle DB.  I have been looking to enable/add a "SQL Query node source".
["Add a new Node Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR53e.png)
Should that be visible after adding this plugin or do I need to add some config?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the resource.xml/yaml file with the specific plugin parameters (and that is the plugin source, not a new kind of source in the source list).

To create the file in your project:

1. Go to the Project Settings > Edit nodes.
2. Click on the Add a new source button.
3. Select "File".
4. Select resourcexml, define the path (including the file), click on Generate and Writeable and save.
5. Save your source.
6. Now go to the Edit tab, and click on the Modify button. Look.
7. Add the SQL node entry inside `<project>` tag, for example:

```xml
<node name="remotehost" 
node-executor="jdbc-command" 
db-type="oracle" 
jdbc-connect="jdbc:oracle:thin:@remotehost:1521:ee122" 
jdbc-username="system" 
jdbc-password="system" 
description="" 
tags="" 
hostname="remotehost" 
osArch="amd64" 
osFamily="unix" 
osName="Linux" 
osVersion="" 
username="root"/>
```

8. Now the node is available on your nodes page.

Full configuration explained [here](https://github.com/strdn/rundeck-jdbc-executor-plugin#configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info.
I had created that same file and had connectivity to my DB.  I was struggling to get a successful SQL query and had noticed that there might be an option to create SQL straight from a "SQL Resource Model Source" in my sources config.  I later found out that this is only available in the enterprise version and not the community edition.

I played around with groovy and have created the appropriate query there.

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a comment to an answer. Please use comments and/or edit your initial post to add extra information to the question