# Connecting to AWS RDS instances using Rundeck Community Version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rundeck

I have rundeck community version 4.13.0 running in a AWS EC2 instance.

I have multiple RDS instances running in the same AWS account.

How can I run sql scripts on multiple selected databases via Rundeck.

There are community plugins for AWS EC2 and S3.

But I am unable to find any such plugin for RDS.

Can someone help

Answer (score 0):

Process Automation (formerly "Rundeck Enterprise") includes out of the box the [SQL Runner plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/sqlrunner.html#sqlrunner-plugin-enterprise) to dispatch SQL scripts against any database.

For Rundeck Community, you can use [this](https://github.com/strdn/rundeck-jdbc-executor-plugin) third party plugin. Take a look at the configuration instructions [here](https://github.com/strdn/rundeck-jdbc-executor-plugin#configuration) (take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69617057/10426011) too) and [here](https://github.com/strdn/rundeck-jdbc-executor-plugin#usage) to know how to use it.

Comment: Getting the below error while running 'gradle clean build'

Comment: 2023-06-20T13:48:47.366+0000 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Build file '/home/ec2-user/repo/rundeck-jdbc-executor-plugin/build.gradle' line: 14

Comment: [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating root project 'rundeck-jdbc-executor-plugin'.
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not find method compile() for arguments [{group=org.rundeck, name=rundeck-core, version=3.3.7-20201208, ext=jar}, {group=org.rundeck, name=rundeck-storage-api, version=3.3.7-20201208, ext=jar}, commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6, org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:2.4.21, org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-jsr223:2.4.21] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.